# HTML container expand to fit largest child

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a div to be as wide as the largest element inside. This is what I have come up with, which works pretty well, but relies on all elements being the same size (or at least identifying the tallest element and adding the extra class to it)

```css
.outer {
    background: silver;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.element {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
}

.last {
    height: auto;
}

.small { font-size: xx-small; }
.large { font-size: xx-large; }
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
        <div class="element">a pretty short one</div>
        <div class="element">quite a long long one here</div>
        <div class="element last">super short</div>
</div>

<hr>
<!-- perhaps easier to see without text overlapping -->
<div class='outer'>
        <div class="element">"""""""""""""""""""""""""</div>
        <div class="element">-------------</div>
        <div class="element last">.....................</div>
</div>

<hr>
<!-- layout breaks when element used to set height is not as tall as other elements -->
<div class='outer'>
        <div class="element small">a pretty short one</div>
        <div class="element large">quite a long long one here</div>
        <div class="element last">super short</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this with CSS when the heights are also different to each other, and unknown?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Both container divs appear to be as wide as the widest child.

Comment: Are these all elements suppose to appear inline or in a column?

Comment: @j08691 yes - it works how I want it to, but my solution relies on the height of one of the elements setting the height for the container. I want a solution which would work for elements of any height.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need your existing css for .last or .element.

`<div>` is a block element, meaning it will span 100% width by default.  You were on the right path with setting the outer element to `display: inline-block`.  However, since the .element divs are 100% width as well, they will still break to a new line.  Just change your .element css to display inline-block and you should get the result you're looking for.

```
.element {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work - they all just line up horizontally when I try that: http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/1br1gj9k/

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to do?  If you remove the .element style altogether, you have 3 stacked divs, with the .outer div expanding to the largest width.  http://jsfiddle.net/1br1gj9k/1/

Comment: I am trying to get them to overlap - like in my first two examples - but just to work with arbitrary heights. It is for a toggle button, which needs to remain the same size when toggled on or off, regardless of the size of the on/off text (or elements). I am planning to make one or the other element invisible, but the space taken up by the element will still be the same as the largest element.

Answer (score 0):

What might work is changing your `width` to `min-width` and then if the `width` is larger than the `min-width` constraint it will expand to fill the rest of the content.